# Different domains and ranges of the same Chebyshev polynomial?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

Suppose I have a Chebyshev polynomial $T_2=\cos{(2\arccos(x))}$. Its range is $[-1,1]$ and its domain is $[-1,1]$.

At the same time: $T_2=\cos{(2\arccos(x))}=2\cos^2{(\arccos(x))}-1=2x^2-1$ which has range of $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and domain of $[-1, +\infty)$.

How is this possible? Why can the same function have different domains and ranges? Probably missing something basic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) are defined for any $x \in \Bbb R$ (or
even $x \in \Bbb C$), e.g. via the recurrence relation
$$
  T_0(x) = 1 \\
  T_1(x) = x \\
  T_{n+1}(x) = 2x T_n(x) - T_{n-1}(x)
$$

They satisfy the equation
$$
  T_n(\cos \theta) = \cos (n \theta)
$$
for all $\theta \in \Bbb R$ (and this characterizes
the Chebyshev polynomials uniquely).

For $x \in [-1, 1]$ you can set $\theta = \arccos x$ and get
$$
 T_n(x) = \cos (n \arccos x) \quad \text{ for } {-1} \le x \le 1
$$
which shows that the **restriction** of $T_n$ to $ [-1, 1]$
maps this interval onto $ [-1, 1]$.